# How can I select a sentence containing a <strong> tag?

Tags: javascript

I’m parsing HTML in order to pick up on certain tags that can have their text copied, and would like to know how to grab sentences in a paragraph containing a strong tag. For example, I would like to grab:

```
<p>The <strong>cells</strong> are  big.</p>
```

And,

```
<p><strong>Cells</strong> are huge.</p>
```

Are there any jQuery or plain JavaScript techniques I can use to identify these tags and get their content?

Comment: You don't need to use regex to do this, you can just use the DOM, also, I don't think regex can interact with html elements as it only deals with a pattern of characters. Check this link out to learn more about regex https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Answer (score -1):

Using [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent):

```js
const $pOne = document.getElementById('p-one')
const $pTwo = document.getElementById('p-two')
console.log($pOne.textContent)
console.log($pTwo.textContent)
```

```html
<p id="p-one">The <strong>cells</strong> are  big.</p>
<p id="p-two"><strong>Cells</strong> are huge.</p>
```